# why my SQL Server 2008 R2 has an internal version 661 instead of 665?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

According to [thislink](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/07/17/internal-sql-server-database-version-numbers.aspx) and [thislink](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/zh-CN/3691f370-d434-4742-9ab6-c4fb88c968dd/sql-version-661-and-665), the internal version number of sql server 2008 r2 should be 665, but when I check my instance I got 661 instead. Why?

### The script I'm using is:

```
SELECT @@Version AS Version
     , SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition
     , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion
     , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel
     , DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'version')
```

### The result is:

> Version   Edition ProductVersion  ProductLevel    VersionInternal Microsoft
>   SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) icrosoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
>   Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit)
>   10.50.1600.1  RTM 
>   661

Comment: Those links are in error: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-r2-bumps-the-database-version/ I think there are multiple service packs for R2 that bump the version number.

Comment: @user814064 : Thing is, I installed 2008R2 RTM, no other service pack installed after that.